# Spring Security Oauth2 - java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

im try to follow this tutorial : https://adamzareba.github.io/Secure-Spring-REST-With-Spring-Security-and-OAuth2/

Everything work fine until create/store token

dont know what wrong with org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor

Spring boot : Java 8 : Mysql

Stacktrace..

```
2021-12-15 18:41:09.045 ERROR 18284 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: IllegalArgumentException, java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.util.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:23) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.serializeAuthentication(JdbcTokenStore.java:393) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.storeAccessToken(JdbcTokenStore.java:152) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.createAccessToken(DefaultTokenServices.java:122) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.getAccessToken(AbstractTokenGranter.java:72) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.grant(AbstractTokenGranter.java:67) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.CompositeTokenGranter.grant(CompositeTokenGranter.java:38) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer$4.grant(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.java:583) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:132) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
```

Comment: How are you reproducing this error? Looking at the tutorial, is it when you are attempting to invoke your token endpoint?

Comment: this error popup when i try to get token
 
i try to debugging---

------ authen with oauth2 - ok
------ authen with user admin admin1234 - ok
------ stacktrace show error at JdbcTokenStore

Comment: fyi try inMemory() work fine
---------------------------
clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client")
        .secret("$2a$04$soeOR.QFmClXeFIrhJVLWOQxfHjsJLSpWrU1iGxcMGdu.a5hvfY4W")
        .scopes("read-write")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password");